# The gods and goddesses of the Universe

Tags: gods, goddess

The Universe is continuously expanding, with new suns and planets. Do all the planets have a deity and how are these gods born are they the sons and daughter's of gods from other planets ?

Comment: scripture is unclear on this. Some interpret that a cycle or kalpa refers to individual star systems with life. Other interpret it as the entire universe. Some interpret it that there is only one universe, others interpret it that there are multi verses. If one accepts a kalpa for every star with life, then each would have a Brahma and the subsequent gods of that creation. The matter and energy of the universe come out of Brahman, after that comes Brahma who uses the matter to create living beings. So every star would not need a Brahma, only those with living beings.

Comment: "The universe is continuously expanding with sun and planets"? is this a scientific concept or you've found in any scripture?

Comment: @Pandya does not the exhalation of Lord Vishnu create innumerable Universe's. And I believe science has recorded factual evidence of the expansion of the Universe and also some of the physical ways of galaxies forming. So both is the answer.

Comment: @FrankHestermann "does not the exhalation of Lord Vishnu create innumerable Universe's." that is only for Gaudiya Vaishnava's who believe in Brahma samhita. Most people do not believe in this (for good reasons).

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda@Pandya@Wikash_Hindu " Hindu Scriptures are "unclear" or have differences of "opinion" (for good reason ?)  Why ??  We have a mayor problem in Hindu scriptures and their interpretations. It must be the old blindfolded men and Elephant story again.

Comment: The thrust of the Upanishads is Brahman is the only Reality. The vedas are meant to teach man how to live in accordance with Dharma. It is not meant to be a guide to the physical workings of the universe. The accepted physical theories of the universe are vastly different than what was accepted science of 100 years ago. The accepted scientific theories of today will no doubt be very different in another 100 years.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda great info no one told me it helps me understand the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

We can’t keep creating gods for each planet or star that is born! So in short, there are no gods or goddesses for each and every planet.

But of course, we have the Navagrahas. These Navagrahas are nine gods:

Surya-Sun 
Chandra-Earth’s Moon 
Mangala-Mars 
Budha-Mercury 
Brihaspati-Jupiter 
Shukra-Venus 
Sanishwara-Saturn 
Rahu-Eclipse 
Ketu-Comet

They are praised in the following Shloka:

> *Ādityāya ća Somāya Mańgalāya Budhāya ća* | 
>   *Guru Śukra Śani bhyasća Rāhave Ketave Namah* ||
>
> I worship Aditya (Surya) and Soma (Chandra), Mangala and Budha,
>   Guru (Brihaspati), Shukra and Shani (Sanishwara), Rahu and Ketu.

And again as mentioned, there are no gods or goddesses for each and every planet. Actually, there are no other gods related to planets/heavenly bodies other than the Navagrahas.

It is interesting to note that these Navagrahas are composed of gods of heavenly bodies/phenomena that can be seen with the naked eye from Earth. This CAN explain why there is no god for Uranus and Neptune.

Comment: The question is about other stars and planets revolving around them. It's not about navagrahas and our solar system.

Comment: "We can’t keep creating gods"...who is we here...?